# DemandTools Modify Select Records Criteria with Contains and leading space

Tags: duplicate-management, sales-cloud

I'm building out a modify to my Accounts object with DemandTools.  We have record types for People (Households) and Businesses/Churches (Organizations) - I'm trying to change some businesses with INC in their name but Vince also contains those 3 letters.  I really want " INC" - with a blank space before the inc letters.  When I add the quotes in my record selection criteria I use the quotes but they go away.  How can I achieve my space+INC query?

Comment: You'll have to check with DemandTools support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with the DemandTools Community the best answer was to use the

> % inc%

This allowed for any time a space preceded the i, n, c, letters of any case.

See comments here: [Community](https://mycommunity.validity.com/t5/demandtools/search-for-inc-but-getting-vince-really-want-quot-inc-quot-but/td-p/491)